# How does Coinbase create this effect? Can it be replicated in React? (Prepositioned Dropdown menu on Button hover/click)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui

Here you can see that when I hover over Businesses, a prepositioned section comes onto the screen, just like a dropdown menu. This also spans the width of the screen. How is this achieved and can this be replicated in React? (If it wasn't already coded in React)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's called a Mega menu and there's a npm package for that which can be customize for your needs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mega-menu

If you want to build it from scratch I would suggest you take a look at `useState` and `useEffect` for react.